Issue with Grafana and BigQuery Plugin: Large Query Results Not Returning
Issue with Grafana and BigQuery Plugin: Large Query Results Not Returning
I'm experiencing an issue with Grafana when using the official BigQuery plugin. Specifically, the problem arises when I execute queries that are expected to return large results (over 100,000 rows). The query executes on BigQuery without any errors, but the results never return to Grafana.
Instead of the expected data, I receive the following error message:
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>

This issue only occurs with large result sets. Smaller queries return results as expected. I've tried adjusting various settings in Grafana and BigQuery but haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Steps to Reproduce

Create a data source in Grafana using the official BigQuery plugin.
Execute a query in Grafana that returns over 100,000 rows.
Observe that the query executes in BigQuery but the results do not return to Grafana, and the error message is displayed.

Environment

Grafana Version: v10.2.0
BigQuery Plugin Version: 1.4.0
BigQuery Dataset Size: Over 10,000,000 rows

What I've Tried

Ensured that the BigQuery dataset permissions are correctly configured.
Verified that the query executes successfully in the BigQuery console.
Adjusted keep_alive_seconds and timeout under dataproxy in the Grafana settings

Questions

Is there a known limitation with the Grafana BigQuery plugin regarding large result sets?
Are there any configurations or settings that can be adjusted to handle large query results better either within Grafana or on Gcloud?
Has anyone encountered similar issues, and if so, how did you resolve them?

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
